# How to manipulate index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
rx
10:06:33    928000
10:06:34    400000
10:06:36    632000
10:06:46    712000
10:06:48    736000
10:06:49    856000
10:06:51    736000
10:06:58    728000
10:07:01    760000
Name: size, dtype: int64
```

and this is the type of my index.

```
Index([u'10:06:33', u'10:06:34', u'10:06:36', u'10:06:46', u'10:06:48',
       u'10:06:49', u'10:06:51', u'10:06:58', u'10:07:01'],
      dtype='object', name=u'rx')
```

I want to manipulate my index to start from 0 but also if you can see I have time difference. So 10:06:33 should be 0 and 10:06:34 should be 1 and 10:06:36 should be 3. As you can see there are seconds "missing" in between and thats why I cannot simply use `df= df.reset_index(drop=True)`. Also my data in the other column should have value zero where a second is missing. so my dataframe should look something like this:

```
rx
0    928000
1    400000
2    0
3    632000
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
10   0
11   0
12   0
13   712000
14   0
15   736000
16   856000
17   0
18   736000
19   0
20   0 
21   0
22   0
23   0
24   0
25   728000
26   0
29   0
28   760000
Name: size, dtype: int64
```

Basically I want to plot my df but with time starting from 0 and for every second from 10:06:33 to 10:07:01. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: is your index supposed to be  a timestamp or timedelta ? at the mo its an object (string)

Comment: I get error "TypeError: difference() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

Comment: I am using datetime.strptime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert times to strings and convert to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and converting to series, get seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and cumulative sum and last use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.index = (pd.to_timedelta(df.index.to_series().astype(str))
              .dt.total_seconds()
              .diff()
              .fillna(0)
              .cumsum())

df = df.reindex(range(int(df.index.max()+1)), fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
      size
rx        
0   928000
1   400000
2        0
3   632000
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       0
11       0
12       0
13  712000
14       0
15  736000
16  856000
17       0
18  736000
19       0
20       0
21       0
22       0
23       0
24       0
25  728000
26       0
27       0
28  760000
```

Comment: I am getting an error "df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index).total_seconds().to_series().diff().fillna(0).cumsum()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_series'"

Comment: @Mohammed - You can change `df.index` to `df.index.astype(str)`

Comment: @Mohammed - Maybe some oldier pandas version, answer was edited. added `df.index.to_series().astype(str)` and `.dt.` and removed `to_series()`